# What is the best practice to change variables in automations

Tags: linux, text-processing, packer

I am trying to create auto install Ubuntu OS with packer on Hyper-V and I have project like this:

```
packer-main/
|
|--->http/
|       |--->user-data
|
|--->templates/
|        |--->build.pkr.hcl
|
|--->variables
|         |--->pkrvars.hcl
```

content in user-data

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  version: 1
  identity:
   hostname: jammy-daily
   username: ubuntu
```

content of pkrvars.hcl

```
hostname = "jammy-daily"
username = "ubuntu"
```

and build.pkr.hcl

```
...

ssh_username = "${var.username}"
vm_name = "${var.hostname}"

...
```

My challenge lies in the need to dynamically modify variables within the user-data before initiating the build process. While I am aware that PowerShell scripts or Bash scripts can serve this purpose, I am curious if there are specialized tools available for streamlining such automations. I am also interested in learning about best practices for creating automated infrastructures.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much any of the server/network configuration management (often called "orchestration") tools can use templates to generate file data that you could put into a user_data parameter.  Ansible and Saltstack use Jinja2 templating natively; Chef, Puppet, and Terraform also support Jinja2.

You may find that user_data is better generated (and variables replaced with values) when a virtual machine is launched from an image, rather than when the image is created by Packer.  If your hostname is embedded in your image, then you need to build a different image for each host (VM) in your network.

By contrast, when host-specific info is not baked into the image, a single image can be used by multiple VMs, and the host-specific info can be put into user_data when the VM is launched.  It requires a config management/orchestration tool to do the launching, but in the long run you're saving effort by reducing the number of images to build and maintain.  Just a thought.

Comment: Thanks for a thought, I not even thought about it to create one base image and then build from that image another images..